# Need Help On CoreData Saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to insert values into core data object, but while saving those values am getting `null` response, but it's getting updated into Core data database,

Used Code:

```
AllAssets *allAssets1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllAssets" inManagedObjectContext:context];

allAssets1.assetID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:assetID];
allAssets1.originalassetname = assetName;
[images addObject:[showrelatedAssets objectAtIndex:i]];

[products addObject:allAssets1];

[show_AddtoOffline addRel_Assets:products];
```

getting `null` from below `NSLog` statement,

```
if ([images count] !=0 ) {

        if ([context save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's giving you `null`. Your data is saved without any error, and you are logging `error` and `[error localizedDescription]`.

Since there is no error, these will be `null`.

The method `save:` of `NSManagedObjectContext` returns `YES` if save is successful, and `NO` if save fails. In the latter case, it also stores the error encountered in the `&error` address you have passed.

Your `if` statement should be:

```
if ([context save:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Save successful");

} else {

    NSLog(@"Could not save: %@ | %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([context save:&error])
 {
    // This means your data is saved properly

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong ? From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:)

> - (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
>
> Return Value
>   YES if the save succeeds, otherwise NO.

So when you enter the loop, save was successful and error is still null.